# Loop through paragraphs in object. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

The following javascript object contains 2 paragraphs. I am having a hard time figuring out how to output them dynamically. Perhaps a loop? But the paragraphs are child objects with their own child properties. I need to access these in a row and append them to `modal-section-body` container.

Do feel free to suggest an object redesign.

```js
            // Sample Modal Object
            var modalDefaults = {

              // depth 0
              modalId: 'modal6',
              
              // depth 0
              modalHeader: {
                icon: 'headerIcon',
                iconColor: 'headerIconColor',
                mainTitle: 'headerTitle',
                subTitle: 'headerSubTitle'
              },

              // depth 0  
              modalBody: {
                title: 'bodyTitle',
                abrv: 'bodyAbrv',
                subTitle: 'bodySubTitle',

                //depth 1
                paragraph1: {
                  //depth 2
                  title: 'Paragraph 1 Title',
                  body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1.'
                },

                //depth 1
                paragraph2: {
                  //depth 2
                  title: 'Paragraph 2 Title',
                  body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2.'
                }

              },

              // depth 0
              modalFooter: {

                  //depth 1
                linkOk: {
                  //depth 2
                  color: 'linkOkColor',
                  icon: 'linkOkIcon',
                  label: 'linkOkLabel',
                  href: './'
                },

                //depth 1
                linkCancel: {
                  //depth 2
                  color: 'linkCancelColor',
                  icon: 'linkCancelIcon',
                  label: 'linkCancelLabel',
                  href: './'
                }
              }
            };




            console.log(modalDefaults.modalId);

            console.log(modalDefaults.modalHeader.icon);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalHeader.iconColor);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalHeader.mainTitle);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalHeader.subTitle);

            console.log(modalDefaults.modalBody.title);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalBody.abrv);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalBody.subTitle);

            console.log(modalDefaults.modalBody.paragraph1.title);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalBody.paragraph1.body);

            console.log(modalDefaults.modalBody.paragraph2.title);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalBody.paragraph2.body);

            console.log(modalDefaults.modalFooter.linkOk.color);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalFooter.linkOk.icon);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalFooter.linkOk.label);

            console.log(modalDefaults.modalFooter.linkCancel.color);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalFooter.linkCancel.icon);
            console.log(modalDefaults.modalFooter.linkCancel.label);
```

Comment: Man i am not sure what did you mean by how to access them.Because you have clearly accessed them in the `console.log` statement.I bet no one will help you redesign your object shape, because we do not know the context.Do you mean that the paragraphs are dynamic and the amount of them varies?If the amount of them vary i would make 'paragraphs' property in the modalBody an array (of objects) and manipulate/access it as an array not an object.

Comment: The context are the contents of a dynamic bootstrap modal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
let modalBody = modalDefaults.modalBody;
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(modalBody)) {
    if (/paragraph(\d)/.test(key)) {
        $('.row').append($(document.createElement('h1')).text(value.title));
        $('.row').append($(document.createElement('p')).text(value.body));
    }
}
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/yetrvm1j/2/)

Comment: That would do it but keep in mind that the order of appended elements would not be the same as they were provided in an object.

Comment: Please, do feel free to propose your array idea. I find it interesting especially because I will need the paragraphs to output in order.

Comment: @ASPiRE As you can see this in [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/6ncbua57), if you have two paragraphs that first has `paragraph333` and second has `paragraph12`, but the order of them is correct by using `Object.entries`. Just, if  paragraphs have _integer_ id like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/r6m5xjfv/1/), there is no grantee for orders. So, my code for your situations that have `paragraph` prefix works properly.

Comment: @JanCiołek Tanks for notice that. Just, if paragraphs have integer id like this, there is no grantee for orders but it works properly when we have `paragraph` prefix you can see my examples in my previous command.

Comment: @ASPiRE Create property `paragraphs` in modalBody which is an array of paragraphs.`{modalBody:{paragraphs:[{title:1,body:1}, {title:2,body:2}]}}` and use similiar logic as @Ali Soltani has provided for you.